# Pika: Write buffer exceeded warning

Tags: python, rabbitmq, pika

Our software program was working fine for 5 months and now suddenly we have started receiving Pika warnings which ultimately lead to an exception.

Pika 0.9.5 UserWarning: Write buffer exceeded warning threshold.

I have searched many forums, but to very little satisfaction. One solution described was to ignore these warnings altogether, but I am a little skeptical about that. Any help in this matter will be greatly appreciated. It is very urgent.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

This: http://lists.rabbitmq.com/pipermail/rabbitmq-discuss/2011-April/012223.html
explains the problem well. **The problem is that you write much faster than consume from the queue**. And the warning just tells you about that.

You can tune:

```
connection.set_backpressure_multiplier(NNNN)
```

but this will not solve the problem, just will hide the warnings for some time.

Depending on the application - you might need to attach some code to `add_backpressure_callback`:
http://pika.github.com/connecting.html#adapters.select_connection.SelectConnection.add_backpressure_callback

and to do some cleanup or whatever is needed when backpressure is being hit. But first of all - check your code and find what's causing the overload.